# Two ways to assign elements of std::vector

Tags: c++, vector

As far as I am aware, one can assign elements to a `std::vector` in two ways:

`vec[i] = value`

`vec.push_back(value)`

However the first method doesn't appear to have an effect on `vec.size()`, and is also overwritten by subsequent calls to `vec.push_back()`. A minimal example to demonstrate:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

int main()
{
    std::vector<unsigned char> things;
    things.reserve(2);

    things[0] = 'a';
    std::cout << "Size after inserting a: ";
    std::cout << things.size() << std::endl;

    things.push_back('b');
    std::cout << "Size after inserting b: ";
    std::cout << things.size() << std::endl;

    std::cout << "Contents: ";
    for (int i=0; i<2; i++)
    {
        std::cout << things[i] << std::endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

The output of this program is:

```
Size after inserting a: 0
Size after inserting b: 1
Contents: b
```

So could someone please explain:

1. Why is the size 0 even after we insert `'a'`?
2. Why does `things.push_back('b')` overwrite the `'a'`?

Note: I am using `unsigned char` because I've adapted this code from a program I'm writing that involves manipulating this type.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Correction: `vec[i] = value` doesn't do an insert.

Comment: `things[0] = 'a';` assigns something to an inexistent element. This is undefined behaviour, but if you compile with debug mode (how to do this depends on your platform, IDE, compiler, environnment, etc.) this will most likely show a diagnostic during run time.

Comment: reading documentation can help sometimes. The two methods are strictly speaking doing something completely different

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`reserve` doesn't actually change the size of the vector. It only changes the capacity of the vector - that is different from its actual size (see [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/capacity/) for an explanation of what it actually is). So your call of `things[0] = 'a';` is past the size of the vector as it still has size 0 and therefore undefined behavior.

If you call `resize` instead, you get this:

```
Size after inserting a: 2
Size after inserting b: 3
Contents: a
```

Now the vector contains a `'a'`, a `'\0'` and a `'b'`. The `'\0'` is there because that's the default value of `unsigned char`, so `things.resize(2);` leaves the vector with two of those before you change one to an `'a'`.

Comment: Many thanks! I accepted your answer due to the extra details about `\0` at the end, the suggesting the alternative of `resize`.

Answer (score 5):

1. You didn’t insert it, you assigned to an element that doesn’t exist. This has undefined behaviour. Assigning does not extend the vector.
2. Because the vector was empty, `push_back` added the first element.

Answer (score 0):

One more info

```
std::vector<unsigned char> things;
things.reserve(2);
```

Below assignment, without checking the bounds of vector it will write to memory pointed by things[0]. This operation never fails but causes undefined behavior due the corruption of memory.

```
things[0]    = 'a';  // 1
```

---

Below assignment check bounds of vector before writing to memory pointed by things[0]. It fails if the index is not within the bound of vector and throws 'std::out_of_range' exception.

```
things.at(0) = 'a'   //2
```